# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space + java

Tags: java, heap-memory

I am getting following exception when I am going to send the mail with FTL teampate & attaching image with it. Please advice what needs to be done

```
            java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
             at sun.security.provider.certpath.UntrustedChecker.check(UntrustedChecker.java:58)
             at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:117)
             at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.doValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:330)
             at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:178)
             at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:250)
             at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:275)
             at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:263)
             at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:173)
             at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:218)
             at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:126)
             at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:209)
             at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:249)
             at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1185)
             at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:136)
             at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:593)
             at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:529)
             at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:958)
             at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1203)
             at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.writeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:654)
             at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:100)
             at com.sun.mail.util.TraceOutputStream.write(TraceOutputStream.java:101)
             at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
             at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
             at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1418)
             at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.sendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:1408)
             at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.ehlo(SMTPTransport.java:847)
             at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:384)
             at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:297)
             at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
             at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:105)
             at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:168)
             at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:98)
            java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
            Exception in thread "http-bio-8080-exec-17" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
            Exception in thread "bitronix-scheduler" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Answer (score 1):

This error caused by the `PermGen` space, it got filled during the execution time, You can do two thing regarding to this problem:

**First:** increase you `PermGen` size by adding the following parameter:

```
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

**Second:** enable the `GC` on the `PermGen` space to be garbage collected

```
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSPermGenSweepingEnabled -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
```

Comment: note to OP: these flags are jdk, jdk version and jdk vendor specific, so they might not do anything.

Comment: Hey Thanks above solutions workout for me